# Nodejs & Request & Cheerio: Can't add to a global array from within the request

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, request, closures

I am a relatively new javascript developer and I am stuck with an issue that I cannot seem to track down, and I think that I may be looking in the wrong spot.  It looks like it may have something to do with scope/closures but I just cannot seem to get it working.  Here it goes:

I have a globally scoped Array named `arr`.  I am using node.js, request, and cheerio to hit a website and grab information -- in this illustration, the `href` attribute of every link on http://www.google.com.  I am then inserting them into my globally scoped Array.  However, outside of the 'request', the Array still seems to be empty.

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var arr = []
var url = 'http://www.google.com';

request(url, function(err, resp, body)  {
  var $ = cheerio.load(body);
  $('a').each(function(i, link){
    arr.push(link['attribs']['href']);
  });
});

console.log(arr); // prints nothing
```

I know that this is most likely something very simple that I am overlooking but if someone could help me shed some light as to exactly why, I would greatly appreciate it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `arr` is being populated. But the statement `console.log(arr)` is excuated before the request call is completed. This is because of non-blocking property of `node.js`. 
You can log `link['attribs']['href']` inside the loop and you will see that `arr` will be printed first as an empty array `[]`, and then the values inside the loop will be printed afterwards.